# Upload a folder using web driver sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Am trying to build script through JMeter for my application using `web driver sampler`. Basically, I am stuck at `upload a folder (which contains some images)`

**Step 1:** Chose a file element locator for this `Choose File` is `id` 
[image]

Id for Locator is:

[image]

**Step 2:** Locate the hard drive location for example `C:\Download\IMG`

[image]

**Step 3:** After selecting the OS Drive, the pop up windows on the browser window,

[image]

I tried with :

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('file_input_instructions')).sendKeys('C:\\Downloads\\IMG')
```

But not working, any input here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=183

> We have decided not to take action on this issue because of other higher priorities. We'd welcome patches from yourself or other contributors however.

So the only thing you could do is to:

1. Get the list of files absolute paths
2. Amend your code to provide individual file paths

Example [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) snippet:

```
def request = ''

new File('c:/Downloads/IMG').listFiles().each { file ->
    request = request.concat(file.getAbsolutePath()).concat('\n')
}

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('file_input_instructions')).sendKeys(request)
```